# Не могу разобраться в GWT, именно с нажатием на кнопку, а затем смена фона страницы

Tags: java, gwt

```
package com.example.gwt.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class Example implements EntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        Button button = new Button("Click me");
        RootPanel.get().add(button);
        button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Element el = Document.get().getElementById("my-div");
                el.getStyle().setBackgroundColor("#ff0000");
            }


        });
    }
}
```

Вот HTML-код:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello my Dear friend</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <div id="my-div" ></div>
</head>
<body id="bodyId">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
        src="com.example.gwt.Examp/com.example.gwt.Examp.nocache.js"></script>
<h1>Example Application</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: попробуйте добавить в вопрос [mcve]

Comment: почему у вас `<div>` в `<head>`?

Comment: А должен быть в Body?

Comment: Да, должен быть. До того как браться за GWT, стоит разобраться с основами HTML/CSS, т.к. в конечном счете все построено на них.